# JavaScript variable is undefined although it has been defined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototypejs

In the console.log, the var damage is undefined. What am I missing? I have defined damage in the prototype and still no go.  Any ideas? Basically just want a random number generated and then subtract that number from the players health and display the remaining balance as the amount of damage taken.

```
function Player(name, weapons) {
    this.playerName = name;
    this.playerHealth = 10;
    this.playerStrength = 2;
    this.playerWeapons = [];
}

Player.prototype.applyDamage = function(damage) {

    var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var total = this.playerHealth - damage;

    return total;
};
console.log("Player sustained " + damage + " " + "amount of damage.");
```

Comment: please show how this function is called?

Comment: `var damage` is a local variable on scope only inside the function `applyDamage`. Read about scopes here (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the damage variable from the global scope but the variable is defined in the prototype scope.That`s why it's showing undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You define `damage` as a variable *inside* `Player.prototype.applyDamage`, so outside this function `damage` still not be defined

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Javascript have function scope. This means they can only be accessed or assigned to within the function where they are declared, and that they exist everywhere in the function, even if the variable is declared inside a sub-part of the function.

The exceptions are variables declared outside of any function (global variables) and variables that are declared with "let" instead of var. Variables declared with let have block scope.